# How to run Jupyter Notebooks on AWS EMR Spark (AWS EMR Spark Failed to Connect to master or dead executors)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a Spark cluster using AWS EMR and cannot connect to the master node when tunneling pyspark with jupyter notebook.

emr-5.0.0
Spark: Spark 2.0.0 on Hadoop 2.7.2 YARN with Ganglia 3.7.2 and Zeppelin 0.6.1
m3.xlarge

Master node command:
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser --port=7777" pyspark --master spark://ec2-publicDNS.amazonaws.com:7077

I get the following error:
WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master ec2-publicDNS.amazonaws.com:7077

I have also tried the following arguments to –-master:
--master yarn 
rgument results in all executors  (other than the driver) showing up as “Dead” in the SparkUI page.

--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
Results in “Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number”

Is there a preferable way of launching an interactive Jupyter notebook on an AWS EMR Spark cluster? The present way I am working does not seem able to actually use the executor nodes, just the driver.

Comment: EMR uses Yarn and you try to connect through standalone interface.
I think u need livy for jupyter, and EMR doesn't use livy...